# how to make scatter plot of two columns and divide x_axis in 3 column f1,f2,and f3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plotly

I have dataframe i want to draw a scattor plot by dividing plot in 2 regions in region one only plot f_x_f1 vs A_x_f1, and in region2 plot f_x_f2 vs A_x_f2

please if someone can provide better solution for this problem

here is example of my dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'f_x_f1':[0.3,0.28,0.34],'A_x_f1':[0.003,0.28,0.034],'f1':[0.4,0.4,0.4],'f_x_f2':[0.91,0.88,0.96],'A_x_f2':[0.003,0.28,0.034],'f2':[1.3,1.3,1.3]})
```

Comment: it would help a lot if we could see what you've already attempted :) otherwise, you can check the matplotlib documentation (https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) for how to create scatter plots

Comment: i know how to draw simple scattor plot , ax1 = ddd.plot(kind='scatter', x='freq_x_max_f1', y=['Amp_x_max_f1'], color='r')  , but i dont know how to divide plot in 2 regions based on column

Answer (score 2):

Here, using matplotlib!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


### making some sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({"f_x_f1": np.random.randint(1,100,100) 
                    , "A_x_f1": np.random.randint(1,100,100)    
                    , "f_x_f2": np.random.randint(1,100,100) 
                    , "A_x_f2": np.random.randint(1,100,100) })

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
ax[0].scatter(df.f_x_f1,df.A_x_f1)
ax[0].set_title("f_x_f1 vs A_x_f1")

ax[1].scatter(df.f_x_f2,df.A_x_f2)
ax[1].set_title("f_x_f2 vs A_x_f2")
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: @i want to plot in same axis , i uploaded the example picture